# Are there holomorphic functions $ f $ such that $ f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=f\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n^{3}} $?

Tags: complex-analysis

The question:

There exist a holomorphic function, defiened in a nieghbourhood of $0$, such that $$ f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=f\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n^{3}} $$
For any sufficiently large enough $ n \in \mathbb{N} $
?

I think there are no such functions, but Im not sure if my proof is correct. Here's what I thought:

Consider the set $$ \left\{ \frac{1}{n}:n=1,2,3,...\right\}  $$

This set has the limit point $0$, and for each $ z $ in this set, we have $ f\left(z\right)=z^{3} $. Thus, by the uniquness theorem we have $ f\left(z\right)=z^{3} $ for any $ z $ where $ f $ is defined.

But then we get a contradiction because $ f\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n^{3}}\neq\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3} $.

Is this proof holds?

Also, what if the given detail was $ f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=f\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n^{2}} $, In this case I could in the same way, conclude that $ f(z) $ should be $ z^2 $ by the uniqueness theorem, and I do not have any detail that would help me find a contradiction. Does that mean that indeed the only function that sastisfies this condition is $ z^2 $ ?

Im not sure if I'm using the uniqueness theorem correctly, So I'd appreciate if someone would read what I wrote and tell if it makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already proved that $f(z)=z^{3}$. So how can we have $f(-\frac  1n)=\frac 1 {n^{3}}$?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I wanted to make sure that my proof that $ f(z)=z^3 $ holds and that I used the uniqueness theorem correctly.

Comment: You did use the theorem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thus, by the uniquness theorem we have $ f\left(z\right)=z^{3} $ for any $ z $ where $ f $ is defined.

This is not *exactly* correct. Note that you need connectedness of the domain. So you are correct that in a small enough disc around $0$, the function would have to be $z \mapsto z^3$ but note a neighbourhood could have some disjoint disc far away as well.

Apart from that, your argument is fine.

However, the above point does give a bit of a hiccup for the next part that you write.

To elaborate, let $D_1 = \{z \in \Bbb C : |z| < 2\}$ and $D_2 = \{z \in \Bbb C : |z - 43| < 1\}.$ Then, $D_1$ and $D_2$ are open discs which are disjoint. Define $f : D_1 \cup D_2 \to \Bbb C$ as $$f(z) = \begin{cases} z^2 & z \in D_1, \\ 0 & z \in D_2.\end{cases}$$

Then, $f$ is holomorphic, defined in a neighbourhood of $0$, and satisfies $f(1/n) = f(-1/n) = 1/n^2$ for all $n \ge 1$. However, $f(43) \neq 43^2$.